# Python SMTPAuthnticationError

Tags: python, smtp-auth

Up until yesterday I had no issue sending emails with python and now for some reason I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
    mail(name)
  File "/home/runner/mail.py", line 26, in mail
    smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 730, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials p17sm967082ils.71 - gsmtp')
```

I have been using the below code for about 4 months and haven't had any issues. Here is the code I am using to access gmail:

```
import smtplib

def mail(name):
    gmail_user = 'email@gmail.com'
    gmail_password = 'password'

    emaillist = ['email@email.com']

    for email in emaillist:
        sent_from = gmail_user
        to = email
        subject = 'Subject'

        body = "Body"

        email_text = '''\
        From: %s
        To: %s
        Subject: %s

        %s
        '''%(sent_from, to, subject, body)

        try:
            server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
            server.ehlo()
            server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
            server.sendmail(sent_from, to, body)
            server.close()

            print('Email sent!')
        except:
            print('Oops!')
```

I have tried changing the use less secure apps in gmail, enabling IMAP, and changing the password for the email account. So far no luck with solving the issue. Any help would be greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Google has increased its security policies, I invite you to read this link in the part of: **Less secure apps & your Google Account** and open the link like bellow ( Less secure app access)

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

[image]

later Allow access to unsafe applications: YES

Comment: I have tried toggling that but it still does not work.

Comment: but are you sure that you are login with the same account ?

Comment: are using some IDE for execute your script ?

Comment: i am using pythonanywhere to run my script daily but have been using repl to try to resolve the issue. I originally coded the whole thing in repl and it worked both places until yesterday which is when I noticed it stopped working.

Comment: Is possible you can add all code? ..with imports ..(Just all about when you send mail )

Comment: import smtplib

def mail(name):
 gmail_user = 'email@gmail.com'
 gmail_password = 'password'

 emaillist = ['email@email.com']

 for email in emaillist:
  sent_from = gmail_user
  to = email
  subject = 'Subject'

  body = "Body"

  email_text = '''\
  From: %s
  To: %s
  Subject: %s

  %s
  '''%(sent_from, to, subject, body)

  try:
   server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
   server.ehlo()
   server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
   server.sendmail(sent_from, to, body)
   server.close()

   print('Email sent!')
  except:
   print('Oops!')

Comment: if you add it in your code formatted on your question please

Comment: sorry about that its there now

Comment: thank , your code work for me ...I'm using the same version python that you...if you try with another account gmail? ...but aslo allowing permision https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: huh nope another account doesn't work either. what did you use to run it? an IDE?

Comment: I use just a console windows or linux

Comment: huh well i'm stumped

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i don't understand why it works for you but not for me.

Comment: well i just changed the password again and now it works. i don't understand what changed this time but it worked. thanks your help.

Comment: don't worry ... I hope I helped you with your question