# How do I use MIMEMultipart?

Tags: python, mime, smtplib

I want to make a script that sends my homework to my mail every now and then, but they sending a mail part isn't working. I have looked at tutorials, but I still get a mistake when i write 
`msg = MIMEMultipart()`
Is there something wrong with that?
(I use gmail)

```
for name, email in zip(names, emails):
    print("Writing the mail")

    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    # add in the actual person name to the message template
    message = message_template.substitute(PERSON_NAME=name.title())

    # setup the parameters of the message
    msg['From']=Myaddress
    msg['To']=email
    msg['Subject']="Homework"

    # add in the message body
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

    # send the message via the server set up earlier.
    s.send_message(msg)
    print("Mail sent")

    del msg
```

btw I have multiple mails to send it to.
And yes I imported these:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
```

Comment: But Which is the error you have?

Comment: Unindent does not match any outer indentation level (<unknown>, line 139) pylint(syntax-error) [139, 27]
And line 139 is msg = MIMEMultipart()

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments

Comment: I dont see how it helps, because he does the same as me:
msg = MIMEMultipart()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level)

Comment: can you add all your code ? ..pls

Comment: But now I get a new error, too long to type it in here - something about authentication

Comment: Is gmail ?...check this - > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270643/python-smtpauthnticationerror/59271554#comment104752676_59271554

Comment: This is where I get the error:

`s = smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port=465)`
`s.starttls()`
`s.login(Myaddress, Mailpassword)`

Comment: I just did what I should in the link - allow less secure apps, but I still get an error `s = smtplib.SMTP(host="smtp.gmail.com", port=465)` in this line of code. Any idea why?

Comment: TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]

Comment: Ok, somehow it works when just switching to a different pc, probably because my old pc was waaay too slow for the server to start up before taking too long time. Thanks for the help though,  thanks :)